# My JQuery script contents is getting change by something else that's loading on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a jQuery script that I'm having load after the sp.bodyloaded event in a SharePoint page.  I'm not even sure if this has anything to do with SharePoint as I get the same result even if I use $( document ).ready() to run my function.

A lot of characters are being replaced with things like AHO, ADO, etc. I've done this with a few other scripts on different pages and it hasn't acted like this.   Anybody know what might be doing this?

Original code:

```
if (typeof anObject === 'undefined') {
    var anObject = {}; 
}
anObject.childObject = {
    init:function myFunction() {
        //code
        }
}
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(anObject.childObject.init, 'sp.bodyloaded');
```

As it shows up in F12 after it loads:

```
if (typeof anObject +AD0APQA9- 'undefined') +AHs-
    var anObject +AD0- +AHsAfQA7- 
+AH0-

anObject.childObject +AD0- +AHs-
    init:function myFunction() +AHs-
        //code
        +AH0-
+AH0-

SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(anObject.childObject.init, 'sp.bodyloaded')+ADs-
```

Comment: Looks like something is parsing it and doing some sort of URL Encoding. How are you placing the code in your SP? Are you using Designer or Editing via the portal itself?

Comment: Also, are you wrapping the script with `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: The script is in the style library folder.  There is a content editor web part on the page with some embedded html referencing the js file.  <script src="/linktofile/file.js"></script>

Comment: You may want to append `type="text/javascript"` to that tag so the webpart knows whats being included. It should be working properly as is, I can only think that SP is trying to overly protect the webpart for malicious code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Ok, can you review the Console for any errors and make a pastebin of your final code source from the page? I suspect that some other script is not being closed or that some other part of the page is conflicting. Have you tested with a clean page that has no other webparts?

Comment: Try to use utf8 charset in script tag `charset="UTF-8"`